# Creating Oracle Database Table with Numeric Permission Level

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating an Oracle database with a table called Roles.
I want the Permission_Level row to store values 1,2,3,4, or 5.  How to I limit the input to only those numbers?  Here is my attempt:

```
    CREATE TABLE ROLES 
(
  ROLE_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL 
, ROLE_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL 
, PERMISSION_LEVEL NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT ROLES_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    ROLE_ID 
  )
  ENABLE 
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check constraint is one option:

```
SQL> create table roles
  2    (role_id         number(20)   constraint roles_pk primary key,
  3     role_name       varchar2(20) not null,
  4     permision_level int          constraint ch_lvl check
  5                                  (permision_level in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
  6  );

Table created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into roles (role_id, role_name, permision_level) values (1, 'Role 1', 3);

1 row created.
```

Level 10 doesn't fit:

```
SQL> insert into roles (role_id, role_name, permision_level) values (2, 'Role 2', 10);
insert into roles (role_id, role_name, permision_level) values (2, 'Role 2', 10)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_LVL) violated


SQL>
```

Comment: Just a note. Though a convenient shorthand, the `INT` data type corresponds to `NUMBER(38)`, something that may be too big for a column that stores numbers from 1 to 5.

Comment: @TheImpaler I am new to all of this, especially Oracle datatypes.  I struggle knowing what datatype to store certain data in such as this situation of levels 1 to 5.  I will have a similar situation when storing restaurant table numbers 1 to 40.  Can you suggest a datatype for 1 to 5?

Comment: @taraloca For values between 1 and 5, `NUMBER(1)` will be appropriate. For values between 1 and 40 `NUMBER(2)` will work. Of course this assumes you won't need to extend those values beyond 9 and 99 respectively. Otherwise, you should allocate more digits from the beginning.